# Migrating Excel formula to DAX

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I find myself replicating the following Excel formula in DAX:

**NR/hl Cat Mix = (Peso% SKU Act  - Peso% SKU Base) * (NR/Hl Cat Base - NR/Hl Total Base)**

This formula includes the subtraction of two shares "Peso% SKU Act" and "Peso% SKU Base", which I am calculating in DAX as follows:

**Peso% SKU Act = DIVIDE(SUMX(Worksheet,[ACT Volume]),CALCULATE(SUM(Worksheet[ACT Volume]),ALLSELECTED(Worksheet)))**

**Peso% SKU Base = DIVIDE(SUMX(Worksheet,[LE Volume]),CALCULATE(SUM(Worksheet[LE Volume]),ALLSELECTED(Worksheet)))**

The result of both shares is **100%**

My drawback is that the calculation made in excel does not take into account the total result of the participation (100%), but only takes into account the result of each SKU.

Result by SKU in Excel Example

[image]

In Power BI I have not managed to get my result to have the same behavior as the calculation has in Excel, so whenever I subtract the shares that I have in DAX my result is 0 since the total of each shares is 100%

My code in DAX is like this:

NR/hl Cat Mix = (Peso% SKU Act  - Peso% SKU Base) * (NR/Hl Cat Base - NR/Hl Total Base)

Very similar to Excel, but behaves like this:

**NR/hl Cat Mix = (100%  - 100%) * (382.4 - 344.7) =
(      0     ) * (     37.7    ) =
Result DAX = 0**

Correct result evidenced in Excel is 2.1

How can I modify my code so that it has the same behavior and dynamics that Excel has and gives me the correct result?

[Sample Data Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgYZFTdxng_ufGyeH18lgXLk_ck?e=HMRNdn)

Comment: What do you define as SKU?

Comment: I would define SKU, the encoding that each of the records or each row has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform this calculation it is necessary to force the row context as follows:

NR/hl Cat Mix = SUMX(Table, (Peso% SKU Act - Peso% SKU Base) * (NR/Hl Cat Base - NR/Hl Total Base)))